# Finding loops inside linked lists (ex 2.8 from cracking the coding interview)

Tags: list, loops, linked-list, find, hashtable

This follows exercise 2.8 from the book "Cracking the coding interview". There, they ask to find a loop inside a linked list. They propose a fast runner/slow runner approach, but I found a much smaller solution and would like to confirm if there is any type of problem with my solution.

I decided to create an hash table initially "all False" that keeps track of if a node has been visited. Then I do a cycle that runs until the 'current node' has already been visited which ends the cycle:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self,data=None,next=None):
        if data!=None:
            self.data=data
        self.next=next

def find_loop(head,hash_table):

    node=head

    while hash_table[node]==False:
        print(node.next.data)
        hash_table[node]=True

        node=node.next

    node_at_beginning_of_loop=node
    return node.data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    node3=Node()

    node5=Node(11,node3)
    node4=Node(5,node5)
    node3.data=6
    node3.next=node4
    node2=Node(2,node3)
    node1=Node(9,node2)

    hash_table={}

    for i in range(1,6):
        hash_table[globals()['node%s' % i]]=False

    print(find_loop(node1,hash_table))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work however this isn't an 'efficient' solution in terms of space.  The fast/slow runner is O(n) time and O(1) space.  Your solution is O(n) time and O(n) space.  Also, you should be using a HashSet / set in python not a HashMap / dictionary.